# Google Forms Presentation After Submission Page formatting

Tags: google-forms

Would like to bold some text and add a link without the entire address visible on the page shown after a form is submitted

Tried using html tags `<b>Bold</b>` & `<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+a+tes">test</a>` and they just got rendered as text.

Comment: If You want to do this by using the confirmation message that you can edit unter the "settings" tab I'm quite sure that this is not possible. At least You can do the  , but have in mind (if the text is about to be copied/processed) that these are no regular letters.

Comment: How would you use bold characters? Attempted the mini-Markdown formatting, that is displayed when clicking add a comment here, and that didn't work either `[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code``

Comment: Unicode includes a couple of font variants of the latin character set  ,   . Most systems doesn't treat these as letters so they will not be found by regular text search. As this does probably not affect Your use case You might use them anyway. :-) There are online text converters like https://tools.picsart.com/text/font-generator/ helping You.